# Datepicker dropdown lists not align in one row

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working with **JQuery Datepicker** with international languages.

When I change the language to **Traditional Chinese**, the Month and Year dropdown list in Datepicker will be updated. However, the alignment of the two dropdown list becomes different.

I have no idea how to align the two dropdown lists horizontally, can anyone help?

[image]

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15KpK.png)

Comment: Try changing font size in drop down.

Comment: add code what u have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to answer whithout any code.

But you can try to add some css to your inputs dropdown :

```
input.dropdown{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  line-height:**the height of the input**;
}
```